# Can I re-define a function or check if it exists?

Tags: c, function

I have a question about (re-)defining functions. My goal is to have a script where I can choose to define a function or not.
Like this:

```
void func(){}

int main(){
   if (func)func();
}
```

AND without the function, just:

```
int main(){
   if (func)func();
}
```

Anybody an idea?

Comment: Your syntax does not make sense. Are you trying to cast?

Comment: Is the preprocessor an option? Then you could define a function depending on whether or not a different function is defined, but it will only decide at compile time

Comment: Can't you use precompiler statements, or do you want to define methods dynamically? I'm not sure you can do that.

Comment: @monkey, its a quick setup without casts

Comment: @Tim only with function pointers.

Comment: @Tim: We need clarification here. Your terminology is slightly off, so perhaps it'd be best if you could describe your wider goals?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this in GCC using its weak function attribute extension:

```
void func() __attribute__((weak)); // weak declaration must always be present

int main() {
  if (func) func();
  // ...
}

// optional definition:
void func() { ... }
```

This works even if `func()` is defined in another .c file or a library.

Comment: [Well this is pretty cool.](http://www.kolpackov.net/pipermail/notes/2004-March/000006.html) Yay for GCC. Do other compilers support similar features, or is this pretty much a GCC-only thing?

Comment: Oh, looks like some other compilers do support it as well with the usage of `#pragma weak`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol

Comment: Hah! Technically not a [c] answer in entirety, but it _is_ precisely what the OP is looking for, and what my answer works around a lack of.

Comment: @R.: Why would GCC optimise that away if this is a specific GCC feature?

Comment: Weak symbols and definitions have a lot of uses, this is just one of them. It may work, but I'd look it up and check. I seem to remember a problem like this, whereby gcc's optimizer would optimize out non-NULL checks on function addresses, or equality comparisons between the addresses of different functions (both of which are invalid optimizations with weak symbols).

Comment: @R, I'm using it in this manner in some code of my own; it seems to work on Linux anyway. GCC can't optimize out the `if (func)` unless there actually is a definition in the same compilation unit, as it doesn't know if a definition will be provided by some other compilation unit, or shared library, etc

Comment: Wow, nailed the question. Though I think in 5 years someone's going to come across his code using this extension and WTF.

Comment: @Brian: That's what comments and documentation are for.

Comment: @JAB Personally I'm used to seeing documentation explaining what code does, not explaining why the code I'm looking at isn't C

Comment: @Brian: There's a difference between "being non-portable/a compiler extension to the C standard" and "not being C".

Comment: @JAB: Frankly, it's a pretty fine line.

Comment: how does this work? It still fails at linker step anyway using gcc on my macos

Answer (score 6):

Something like this, I think. Haven't used function pointers much, so I may have gotten the syntax slightly wrong.

```
  void func()
  {
#define FUNC_PRESENT
      // code
  }

  void (*funcptr)();

#ifdef FUNC_PRESENT
      funcptr = func;
#else
      funcptr = NULL;
#endif

  int main()
  {
      if (funcptr)
          funcptr();
  }
```

Comment: Still doesn't do dynamic like he wants. He'll have to check against a runtime condition and set the function pointer manually.

Comment: I don't think that `#define` does what you think it does. Lines beginning with # are scanned and removed from the source file in sequence before compilation begins, so FUNC_PRESENT will always be defined when you get to the `#ifdef`. And putting `#define FUNC_PRESENT` within a function definition has no useful meaning.

Comment: +1: Though I'd be careful about writing the `#define` lexically "inside" the function definition. I get that you are trying to bundle the code together so it's less error-prone to move around, but it might mislead some coders into treating the PP definition as something that only happens when `func()` is called. [edit: or it might mislead programmers into thinking that _you_ thought that, like Brian above]

Comment: Ah, and Xaade's right; you could make this dynamic with creative linking, but then your preprocessor trick goes away. Still, while this is not a ready-made product that the OP can slot in, I think your approach is the right one.

Comment: @Brian: Tomalak understood what I meant. I put the `#define` inside the function definition so that if/when the function definition is removed from the code/header file the code `#include`s, the `#define` will automatically go with it.

Answer (score 4):

Use function pointers, set them dynamically based on runtime conditions, and check for null pointers or wrap them in methods that do that check for you.

Only option in C I can think of.

In C++ you could combine templates and DLLs to dynamically define at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Really the only way that you can "choose to define a function or not" is with C preprocessor directives. For example:

```
#ifdef some_name
void func() {
    do_whatever();
}
#else
  //the else part is optional
#endif
```

To set these "variables" you use `#define some_name`

The trouble is, all of this needs to be done at compile time (before that, actually) so it can't be done with an `if` statement like in your example. If you want an if statement to control your program flow, just use it and don't bother with trying to rename functions or using function pointers or something.

Comment: This is probably the most appropriate answer - C is not that good for doing very dynamic stuff.

Comment: +1 Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234755/does-ifdef-or-other-preprocessor-directives-work-for-function-declarations-t

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

I guess that you are trying to do this:

- Two modules, `a.o` and `b.o`
- `b.o` contains a definition for `void foo()`
- `a.o` calls `void foo()` *only* if `b.o` is also linked into the final executable.

This could be useful for a "plugin" system.

---

## Variation 1

You can simulate it using function pointers. I don't know enough C to write this in proper C code, but pseudocode looks like this:

### a.h

```
extern collectionOfFuncPtrs_t list;
int addFuncPtr();
```

### a.c

```
#include "a.h"

collectionOfFuncPtrs_t list;
int addFuncPtr(FuncPtr p) {
   - add func ptr to list
   - return 0
}

int main() {
   - loop through list of function pointers
   - call functions through them
}
```

### b.c

```
#include "a.h"

void bar() { /* ... */ }

static int dummy = addFuncPtr(&bar);
```

### c.c

```
#include "a.h"

void ayb() { /* ... */ }

static int dummy = addFuncPtr(&ayb);
```

### Conclusion

Now, you can link in `b.o` and/or `c.o` as you wish, and `int main()` will only call `bar()` and/or `ayb()` if they exist.

---

## Variation 2

Experiment with variations on this theme if it looks like it may be useful to you. In particular, if you have only a *specific* number of conditionally-defined functions, you could use a bunch of individual function pointers rather than some list:

### a.h

```
extern fptr_t bar_ptr, ayb_ptr;
```

### a.c

```
#include "a.h"

int main() {
   if (bar_ptr)
      bar_ptr();
   if (ayb_ptr)
      ayb_ptr();
}
```

### b.c

```
#include "a.h"

void bar() { /* ... */ }

fptr_t bar_ptr = &bar;
```

### b_dummy.c

```
#include "a.h"
fptr_t bar_ptr = 0;
```

### c.c

```
#include "a.h"

void ayb() { /* ... */ }

fptr_t ayb_ptr = &ayb;
```

### c_dummy.c

```
#include "a.h"
fptr_t ayb_ptr = 0;
```

### Conclusion

Now either link `b.o` or `b_dummy.o`; and either link `c.o` or `c_dummy.o`.

I hope you get the general idea, anyway...!

---

## Bootnote

This is a *lot* easier in C++ where you can write a module registration system very easily with `std::map`s and constructors.

Comment: Just a note, but in C, a pointer to a function would be assigned in a format such as `return_type (*func_ptr_name)(args) = name_of_function_being_pointed_to_without_trailing_parentheses;`; function pointers are generally required to have the same prototype as the functions they point to, but if you have a typedef for the function pointer (`typedef return_type (*typedef_name)(args);`), you could cast the function being pointed to to the typedef and thus avoid a compiler error (but invite the possibility of causing segfaults or the like at runtime due to incorrect number of arguments and such).

Comment: @JAB: Just a note, but that's not assignment. :)

Comment: My usage of terminology aside, things like `static int dummy = addFuncPtr(&bar);` and `fptr_t bar_ptr = &bar;` would instead be `static int dummy = addFuncPtr(bar);` and `fptr_t bar_ptr = bar;` in C, due to the way functions are treated.

Comment: @JAB: Okie doke. Cheers :) In C++, the two are pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @JAB: Erm, to be fair, [this seems to be the case in C too](http://codepad.org/KgQ0A05V).

Comment: I see. Don't think I've ever seen it actually used in the `&lol` format, though, probably because in cases where you don't know if it's the actual function name or if it's just a pointer to a function [you could segfault if you aren't careful](http://codepad.org/SnmFE025). (This would most likely be a problem in situations where a function takes another function as one of its arguments, and thus you could pass either a function name or a pointer to a function.)

Comment: @JAB: I honestly don't think that there is a distinction. The only way to pass a "function name" in a manner other than as a function pointer would be lexically, inside a string. [edit: oh, I see what you mean. Well, taking the address of a function _pointer_ is something quite different. I concede that there may be an element of error-prone-ness here. Still, there is no such thing as "passing a function name"; you're talking about passing a function pointer vs passing a pointer to a function pointer.]

Answer (score 0):

In C? Only by using the preprocessor as stated in other answers.

C isn't a dynamic language like, say, Python.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do what I think you're asking about in C is to use [function pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html). You can take the address of a function, assign it to a variable, test it for nil, etc. However, plain old C isn't a very dynamic language; you might be better off using a different language.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind compiler specific extension, you can use `__if_exists`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

// uncomment the following, and it'll still work
void maybeFunc(){ cout << "running maybe" << endl; }

int main(){
    cout << "hi!" << endl; 
    __if_exists(maybeFunc)
        cout << "maybe exists!" << endl; 
        maybeFunc(); 
    }
}
```

this works in msvc by default, and in clang if you use the `-fms-extensions` flag.