# check if C-style function exists of type 'MyMethodName()'?

Tags: ios, c

This question is geared for iOS version compatibility.

I know how to check if a function exists if it is a typical Objective-C style method using respondsToSelector. i.e. For a method such as:

```
- (void) someMethod:(NSInteger)someParameter;
```

You can use:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod:someParameter)]) {
    //do something
}
```

But what about C-style functions? How can I check if a function exists that looks like:

```
void CStyleFunctionName(FoundationTypeRef parameter);
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a method, it's a function. Possible duplicate of [How to Check if the function exists in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814705/how-to-check-if-the-function-exists-in-c-c) See also: [Can I redefine a function or check if it exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916772/can-i-re-define-a-function-or-check-if-it-exists)

Comment: You can do `if (CStyleMethodName != NULL) { ... }` to see if the symbol is defined. That's what you want to do if you want to be compatible with older versions of iOS for example.

Comment: @FabianKreiser that only works if weak linking is supported.

Comment: I know, but it works in the latest versions of Xcode and @Keller asked more questions about iOS 6 recently and I think he's currently updating an app and wants to make it backwards compatible. ;)

Comment: My question was geared toward iOS so Fabian's solution is the most elegant for that. Also, my endless chagrin for calling it a "method" instead of a "function" :) I've been in iOS land for too long!

Comment: @FabianKreiser submit you solution as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Keller so why is my solution not good enough? Do you really believe it doesn't work on iOS?

Comment: So, you didn't read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html), did you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xcode (at least since 4.3) supports weak linking and you can do the following to see if you can call a C function:

```
// UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() was introduced in iOS 4 in order to support the Retina displays.
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(...);
}
else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext();
}
```

Comment: any idea why do I still get an error on this line?
if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL)

Use of undeclared identifier 'ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion'

Comment: Yeah, the framework is properly linked and I even tried making it weak (optional) lib but to no avail... I was compiling for iOS5 SDK by the way. Never had problem with iOS6

Comment: But did you import the header? `#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>`

Comment: I found out it was caused by the additional framework path that was added on the Build Settings. I am using both iOS5 and iOS6 SDKs in xcode and the I think compiler looks on the iOS5 instead that's why I'm having a problem. (I'm not really sure though...)  It works fine now!

Comment: Where did you see this in the Build Settings, @schystz?  I think I may be having the same problem.  Thanks!

Comment: You can search for "Framework Search Paths" and remove anything you don't need. (Mine is empty bdw)

Answer (score 7):

Dynamic loading:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

void *fptr = dlsym(NULL, "CStyleFunctionName");
if (fptr != NULL) {
    // existent
} else {
    // nonexistent
}
```

Also note that in C, there are no methods, only functions.

Comment: This is great too. But as my question was geared towards iOS, Fabian's solution is more appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: @Keller why is Fabian's solution more appropriate? Why my answer isn't good for iOS?

Comment: It does work. To clarify, Fabian's solution is just slightly cleaner and doesn't require a #include.

Comment: @Keller except that 1. it requires weak linking to be supported, 2. it does need an include: `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: Wow, why are you angry? My answer is just simpler and is recommended in Apple's documentation. It might not be as general as yours, but it's the appropriate way of doing it in this case. Why would you want to call `dlsym()` if the compiler can do that work for you?