# Use system implementation if find, otherwise use my own implementation

Tags: c

I'm try in to use `fls` in my routine. However, not every system has this function. So, I ship my own version of `fls`. I'm wondering if there is any way to let the program use the system implementation and not found, use my own implementation?

```
#include "strings.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int fls(int mask);

int foo(int N)
{
  int tmp = 1 << (fls(N));
  return tmp;
}

/*
 * Find Last Set bit
 */
int
fls(int mask)
{
  int         bit;
  if (mask == 0)
    return (0);
  for (bit = 1; mask != 1; bit++)
    mask = (unsigned int) mask >> 1;
  return (bit);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for `#ifndef fls 'your fls declared here' #endif` preprocessor conditional? (of course on separate lines)

Comment: The most common way is probably to not do this in C, instead use some other tool to check whether `fls` is available, and indicate that to your program, typically through a macro definition, sometimes through filtering the source files to compile. autoconf is one of the tools that can do this, there are plenty of others. Whether this would work for you depends on your build system and your supported systems. Can you provide some details on that?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin not sure. Is this the best practice in this scenario?

Comment: @hvd I think there should be multiple ways doing so. However, I'm wondering what's the best practice in this case. I don't have fancy build system but a ``makefile``.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a weak function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol

> By default, without any annotation, a symbol in an object file is
>   strong. During linking, a strong symbol can override a weak symbol of
>   the same name.

Same question for C++, slightly different from C implementation [Can I re-define a function or check if it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916772/can-i-re-define-a-function-or-check-if-it-exists)

```
int  __attribute__((weak)) fls(int mask){ .. }
```

so if system `fls` is defined as strong, your `fls` implementation will be overridden.

Comment: And are you sure that `__attribute__((weak))` is portable?

Comment: I couldn't find about portability but it is listed under "common function attributes" in gcc.gnu docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes

Comment: That is exactly what I meant: it is a gcc extension, and other compilers do exist..

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Is this solution equivalent with ``#ifndef`` one mentioned in the question comment? Thanks!

Comment: No it defines the function but if there is a file that has a strong definition(normal definition)  for same function compiler Will use that instead weak öne